# Why are my ASP.NET pages returning `200 OK` without any authentication headers being sent?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, keep-alive, httpconnection

#### Note:

> This question has broadened in scope from previous revisions. I have tried to simplify the issue so it can be easily reproduced by anyone.

Using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), I can replay an arbitrary request to my default page after erasing my `Authorization` header from the HTTP request, and I am able to get a response of `200 OK` with valid data.

#### Bounty Update

Here are the steps to reproduce this exact behavior:

**1.** Create a "New Website" in ASP.NET, feel free to name it "InsecureWebsite"

**2.** Edit `web.config` to deny all unauthenticated users:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

**3.** Publish the website to an arbitrary directory on a DEV server and create a virtual directory for the application

**4.** Ensure the application has script access (.ASP) and Integrated Windows Authentication enabled

**5.** Open [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to capture the traffic

**6.** Load the page in your favorite browser and look at the "Inspectors" tab within [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), you'll see a request similar to:

```
GET /InsecureWebsite/ HTTP/1.1
Host: dev.subdomain.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1) Gecko/20090624 Firefox/3.5 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 300
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: NTLM
{Base64-encoded authentication data}
```

The initial request to `Default.aspx` will return a `401 Unauthorized`, will go into negotiation, and then finally return a `200 OK`.

In Fiddler I can then erase the `Authorization` header directly from a replayed request to `Default.aspx` and still get a `200 OK`. How is that possible?

### Solution

It turns out that Fiddler uses the same underlying connection when making the requests, so once the connection is authenticated, any request on the same connection will also be authenticated as the same user as the initial request. You can turn this feature off in Fiddler here:

[Screenshot of Fiddler options http://john.cognitivedelay.com/images/fiddler-options.gif](http://john.cognitivedelay.com/images/fiddler-options.gif)

Once this has been unchecked, any replayed requests from within Fiddler will return a `401 Unauthorized` as I would expect.

Thanks to all who offered their time to respond!

Comment: I recommend you use WCF instead of page methods. It's going to be a lot more flexible, and more likely to have its deficiencies addressed.

Comment: Are you doing the replay in Fiddler itself, or by making a direct connection to the webserver? It might be that Fiddler is reusing an existing HTTP connection (which it can do, as a proxy)... I think IWA might mark the whole connnection as authenticated, not just the current request, which means that any future requests on the same  connection re-use the authorization and authentication from the first negotiation...

Comment: @Stobor - that is exactly it. If you add that as an answer I can award you the bounty

Comment: Hurry up, Stobor, or I will copy/paste your answer :)

Comment: Heya, thanks. Was out of the state, and not near a computer for a while. :-) /me is back at work now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: per updated question:

Are you doing the replay in Fiddler itself, or by making a direct connection to the webserver? It might be that Fiddler is reusing an existing HTTP connection (which it can do, as a proxy)... I think IWA might mark the whole connnection as authenticated, not just the current request, which means that any future requests on the same connection re-use the authorization and authentication from the first negotiation...

Original answer:
Try

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]  
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Authenticated=true)]
```

and see if that helps?

(Possibly `[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role="myDevRole")]` if that's more appropriate for you...)

Answer (score 2):

The Ajax call is done on a new thread for an existing authenticated session, That's why you don't see any authentication information in the headers. The session is already authenticated.

You can get the authenticated user's identity, and then pass that on to any role management routines, by referencing System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]   
public static string WhoAmI()
{
    // Return the identity of the authenticated windows user.
    Return System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
 }
```

Comment: I've recently determined that the scope of the problem is beyond the `WebMethod` call.

Comment: I think you're performing 'session hijacking' with fiddler running as a proxy.  After the session is authenticated, you are using fiddler in place of your browser to perform requests.  Opening a new browser session from the desktop, or using a different browser, should show you that a new session will be created and need authentication.

Comment: So back to your original question regarding the JQuery Ajax call to the webmethod.  It's still not sending headers, right?  It's still not getting a 401, because it's already authenticated.

Comment: The Ajax call was being authenticated like any other page (as I had always thought was the case), except the requests I was creating in Fiddler were using a previously authenticated TCP connection. When that feature was disabled, the Ajax request along with all other requests behave as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially add authentication information to the header of the message, then authenticate yourself in the webmethod.

or you could try something like [this](http://rickgaribay.net/archive/2007/04/04/recipe-wcf-basichttpbinding-with-windows-authentication.aspx)  or [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1407216.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Add this attribute to the web method 
`[PrincipalPermissionAttribute( SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "myDevRole" )]`.

Then on Global.asax event Application_AuthenticateRequest you can make sure that current thread user is authenticated correctly - i.e. do what is necessary to avoid fraud cookies or sessions.

Comment: I tried this exactly and got the same results. Currently, I'm attempting to recreate the behavior I am experiencing and will update the question

Answer (score 1):

Using Windows authentication on your local development machine, every request is going to be from an authenticated user.  So, deny users="?" will never deny any requests locally.

If you were hitting this on a remote IIS machine you aren't authenticated with or were to use Forms Authentication, it would require authentication before you could successfully request either Default.aspx or the page method.

Comment: +1 - Excellent point, but I am uploading to a dev IIS server and am still able to replay requests without an `Authorization` header and get a `200 OK` response. I will update the question to add the steps I've taken to publish

Comment: If it's allowing you to load Default.aspx without authentication, *something* must be representing you to the server as authenticated.  I think your problem's scope isn't as narrow as the service call itself.

Comment: @Dave - you're right again, I can reproduce the behavior by erasing the `Authenticate` header and sending another request to `Default.aspx`, this will drastically change the question since it no longer focuses on just the WebMethod call.

Comment: To isolate your repro to test just page method authentication, how about moving your page method to an ASPX page in a different subdirectory and only apply the deny users="?" to that subdirectory.  If you then make the unauthenticated $.ajax call from a page in the root, it should properly respond with a 401.